# web2py show() function. (explanation of a line of code)

Tags: python, web2py

so this is a function show() which I am trying to understand.
in the model I do have a db.image table where I stored some images which is pointed in the function.

the  only line I am not understanding here is

```
#image = db.image(request.args(0,cast=int))
```

In request.args(0, cast=int) why it has 0 as argument? and what does cast=int does?
the complete function is below:

```
def show():
  image = db.image(request.args(0,cast=int)) or redirect(URL('index'))
  return dict(image=image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.args` is a list-like object. You can index it as you would a normal Python list (e.g., `request.args[0]`), but it also has a `__call__` method that lets you pass in an index to extract a member of the list. The `__call__` method also takes a `cast` argument that tells it to try to convert the value to the specified type. So, `request.args(0, cast=int)` extracts the first member of `request.args` and converts it to an integer (if the cast fails, it will raise an HTTP 404 exception).